# What Is More and Less Uncountable Set

Tags: general-topology

is there set more uncountable than $(0,1)$ and less uncountable than $P((0,1))$, where $P((0,1))$ is the power set of $(0,1)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis

Comment: @TheoBendit This would actually be an instance of the generalized continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Good point Daniel! I missed that. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you are asking whether or not there exists a set with cardinality between the unit interval and the power set of the unit interval. This question is known as the generalized continuum hypothesis. It is known that this question cannot be answered in the standard mathematical logic framework (ZFC).

Comment: It's actually a single case of the generalized continuum hypothesis $\forall \kappa \ge \aleph_0, 2^\kappa = \kappa^+$.  Though as I recall, it *is* a case which has also been proved independent of ZFC.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Well, *every* single case is independent of ZFC ...